# How to add unittest for Kotlin code in the same file and run it?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin

I have some code like this:

```
class Solution {
    fun strStr(haystack: String, needle: String): Int {
        return haystack.indexOf(needle)
    }
}
```

In Python normally I can add some tests in the same file and add something like:

```
<some tests above here>
if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main()
```

To run the unit tests. How do I achieve the same thing in Kotlin ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why tests are normally put into a separate module in Kotlin/Java projects is that, usually, tests need some additional dependencies that do not make sense for production code, like JUnit or other libraries. Also, a test written in the same file would be compiled into a class that is a part of the production code output.

In a project that is published and used as a dependency for other projects, consider not mixing production and test code.

You can, of course, add those test dependencies to the production code. As an example for JUnit, add the dependency (in a Gradle project: `dependencies { compile 'junit:junit:4.12' }`, in an IntelliJ project: [see the reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-libraries.html)), then just add a testing class with a `@Test` function:

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Assert

class Solution {
    fun strStr(haystack: String, needle: String): Int {
        return haystack.indexOf(needle)
    }
}

class SolutionTest {
    @Test
    fun testSolution() { 
        val text = "hayhayhayneedlehayhay"
        val pattern = "needle"
        val result = strStr(text, pattern)
        Assert.assertEquals(8, result)
    }
}
```